# VB.NET: Writing a function that take specific-type, multiple key-value parameters

Tags: vb.net, function, collections, parameters

I'm trying to write a function in a basic MVC (experimental project) that should be called with the following (or as close to):

```
datastore = myTable.FetchData({{column1, constraint1}, 
                  {column2, constraint2}, ... 
                  {colN, conN}})
```

**Function purpose** - It queries a table with the constraints passed to it. For example,

```
FetchData({{Me.Fields("Price"), "<100"}, {Me.Fields("Type"), "=Component"}})
```

will ultimately produce the query

```
SELECT * FROM table a WHERE Price < 100 AND Type = "Component"
```

(the query production is more involved than that, involving relationships defined and so forth, but that's outside the scope of this question)

How should I write the **function definition** to take these parameters?

```
`Public Function FetchData( ??? ) As foobar
```

Essentially, it will be something similar to a Dictionary, since it's a list of pairs of values. However, it needs to be **non-unique** (it could be called to produce `col1 > 1 AND col1 < 5` for eg). A two-dimensional arraylist has been considered also, but each half of the pair needs to be a specific type - the 'key' needs to be of my `ColumnDefinition` object type or string, the 'value' should always be a string.

What would be the best way to handle this?

*Bonus question*: merging the operator in with the constraint (`"=component"`) seems ugly. Any idea about how to write the function def with the operator separate? I tried an enum but that just made it too verbose - I want this to be a fairly easy to use library.

Comment: Is it an option to encapsulate the column and constraint in a class or struct? Then you would just need a param array. You could write a factory to create objects of this class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on .NET 4.0 or higher, suggest trying out the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class to represent your queries. Your code may look like below.

```
Public Function FetchData(ByVal params As List(Of Tuple(Of ColumnDefinition, Char, String))) As foobar
```

Tuples are only recommended for API's under your control, where the context is obvious. If this is a public or shared API, suggest creating a named class with appropriate properties (as in Nico Schertler's comment). Then, the code may look like.

```
Public Function FetchData(ByVal params As List(Of MyContainerClass)) As foobar
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or according to the shape of the function call you are describing, if you are definitely using strings, and it is always {"Col", "Constraint"} then you could do this

```
Public Function FetchData(ByVal MultiDimensionArray(,) As String)
    'this is then how you could pull the pairs of cols and constraints back out
    'where n is the col constraint pair count up to (n) number
    For n As Integer = 0 To MultiDimensionArray.Length - 1
        Dim Col As String = MultiDimensionArray(0, n)
        Dim Constraint As String = = MultiDimensionArray(1, n)
    Next
End Function
```